# Kill all processes for a given user

Tags: posix

Is there a reliable way to kill all the processes of a given user? `kill(-1, SIGKILL)` as that user will work, unless a rogue process of that user kills the killing process first. The best I can find so far is to loop through `system("ps -u")` for that user and kill the processes that way, but that seems really hacky and inefficient.

EDIT: To clarify, I'm specifically asking for a POSIX-compatable solution. For some reason I thought tagging the question posix would put that in the title.

Comment: It's worth noting that all solutions here (as is generally the case with `kill`) have a [TOCTOU](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/367.html) race condition:  between identifying processes to kill and killing them, the process might die and its PID might be recycled.  Or new processes owned by that user might come into being, unknown to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I kill all a user's processes using their UID](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18043/56041), [How to kill all processes in Linux](https://superuser.com/q/161531/173513), [Kill all process of users in Ubuntu?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/35131/56041), etc. Ironic this question was migrated from Stack Overflow to Super User in 2010, yet it is still being asked here.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Just (temporarily) killed my Macbook with

```
killall -u pu -m .
```

where pu is my userid. Watch the dot at the end of the command.

Also try

```
pkill -u pu
```

or

```
ps -o pid -u pu | xargs kill -1
```

Comment: Thanks, but AFAICT killall and pkill aren't part of POSIX (see edit to my question)

Comment: Ah, that's a good one! Looks like it's not possible from library functions defined just in POSIX, so I'll mark this accepted.

Comment: Or you can just type " killall -KILL -u uid". No need to specify -m parameter. Where uid is id of a user.

Comment: Would it not be possible for the user to have 100 processes running, each checking the state of the other processes, and starting a new if one got killed?

Comment: pkill -u pu worked for me.  i was trying to kill processes in the background and too many were running at once to kill each one.

Answer (score 59):

Here is a one liner that does this, just replace username with the username you want to kill things for. Don't even think on putting root there!

```
pkill -9 -u `id -u username`
```

Note: if you want to be nice remove -9, but it will not kill all kinds of processes.

Comment: Save me some breath. Thank you!

Comment: `pkill -9 -u 'username'` - this worked for me on CentOS7.

Answer (score 9):

On Debian LINUX, I use: `ps -o pid= -u username | xargs sudo kill -9`.

With `-o pid=` the ps header is supressed, and the output is only the pid list. As far as I know, [Debian shell](https://wiki.debian.org/Shell) is POSIX compliant.

Answer (score 7):

The following kills all the processes created by this user:

```
kill  -9  -1
```

Comment: According to POSIX, kill -9 -1 is to be interpreted as kill(-1, SIGKILL). "If pid is -1, sig shall be sent to all processes (excluding an unspecified set of system processes) for which the process has permission to send that signal." So by the standard (and, FWIW, on macOS) this will also kill the kill process itself.

Answer (score 2):

What about iterating on the /proc virtual file system ? http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc ?

Comment: Thanks, but /proc isn't part of POSIX (see edit to my question)

Comment: @Shea Levy No problem , please also bear in mind that "ps -u" is also not POSIX per se but more *nix oriented :)

Comment: Hmm, from my reading of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ps.html it seems like it is...