# xargs does not output stdout or stderr

Tags: bash

I have the following bash script

```
ps aux | awk '{print ""$1"\t"$2""}' | grep someuser | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

**this should return**

```
-bash: kill: (922) - Operation not permitted
```

But it doesn't return anything and simply shows me the prompt again.

How can I display `stdout` and `stderr` in the terminal using `xargs`?

UPDATE

```
vagrant@homestead:~/Code/q4$ ps aux | awk '{print ""$1"\t"$2""}' | grep vagrant | awk '{print $2}'
1030
1460
1470
1471
5036
5037
5058
5059
5542
5543
5544
5545
```

Comment: Remove `| xargs kill` and add output to your question.

Comment: See: [Kill all processes for a given user](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15452081/3776858)

Comment: @Cyrus I am not asking about killing a process. I am asking about why xargs does not return `stderr`. I know how to kill a process for a given user

Comment: Your final awk call has a typo...  `awk '{print $2'}`

Comment: @Zlemini I thought I fixed it but for some reason it didn't update. I updated it again. The type doesn't affect the output of xargs.

Comment: Good question! Reproducible and not a word in the xargs manpage about it. It seems to apply to stderr only, cf. `echo 1234|xargs which kill` which *will* output `/bin/kill`

Comment: And yet people want to close this question because it's off-topic..