# Linux "kill -9 <PID>" for all processes?

Tags: linux, bash

[image]

I have a bunch of processes on my school's server that have been running for about a week without it being terminated. I found out that I could use "kill -9 [PID]" for each of the PIDs, but it took me awhile to individually kill each of them.

If, for instance, I have hundreds of processes I want to forcefully kill, is there a way to kill them all instantly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kill all processes for a given user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15452081/608639), [How do I kill all a user's processes using their UID](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18043/56041), [How to kill all processes in Linux](https://superuser.com/q/161531/173513), [Kill all process of users in Ubuntu?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/35131/56041), etc.

Answer (score 1):

You don't linux has number of commands, use the following with caution,  `killall` or you could try `pkill -U UID` or `pkill -U username`

Note when using pkill, it will kill all processes including your tty terminal session if you are using SSH, you will be kicked out!

Answer (score 1):

You can kill process by grep your applicationName. For example

```
ps aux |grep kpark06 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo kill -9
```

Comment: there is `pgrep` for this

Answer (score 0):

`man kill`:

> kill [options]  [...]

**<pid> can be a list.** You can put a giant space-separated list of processes after kill, like `kill 123 543`.

> A PID of -1 is special; it indicates **all processes except the kill process itself
>          and init**

So, `kill -9 -1` will get everything, but that could easily be more than you expect. Having no idea what else is running there, I would only kill *all* the processes if prepared to restart the server.

If these processes have something in common, you may want `killall`, which can filter the processes to kill by age, user, and name/context regular expression, as well as asking for confirmation.

Comment: True, except if you're running as a normal user, you don't have enough permissions to do anything harmful. It'll kill your ssh session but that's easy enough to fix.

Comment: Indeed @o11c! We have no information about who/what started those processes; I figured anything at that scale could involve multiple accounts or otherwise require elevated permissions to stop.